# Update Input Value With jQuery, Old Value Submitted to Form

Tags: jquery, html, forms, input

I've got a form with an input with id/name `league_id`:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/user" method="post">
    <div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">
        <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
        <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="bb92urX83ivxOZZJzWLJMcr5ZSuamowO9O9Sxh5gqKo=">
    </div>
    <input id="league_id" name="league_id" type="text" value="11">
    <select class="sport_selector" id="sport_type_id" name="sport_type_id">
        <option value="5" selected="selected">Football</option>
        <option value="25">Women's Soccer</option>
        <option value="30">Volleyball</option>
        <option value="10">Men's Soccer</option>
    </select>
    <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Save changes">
</form>
```

In another part of my page, I have a drop down that, when changed, clears the value of `league_id`:

```
$("#sport_type_id").change(function(){
    $("#league_id").val(null)
    $(this).parents('form:first').submit()
});
```

If I debug this page, I can see the value get wiped from the text box, but when the form is submitted, my controller always gets the old value.

**UPDATE**

My fault.  I had multiple fields labeled `league_id`.  Not sure exactly what was going on, but I started getting really weird results when I typoed something, and once I ensured all the ID's were unique, I started getting the expected results.

Sorry for the face-palm

I tried changing the name of the input and got the same results.

Comment: Maybe the problem is in controller? For example if it sees that value of this field is empty then it gets old value.

Comment: It's a Rails app, just FYI. While debugging, I see the value come in as the old value. It's not coming in blank, unfortunately

Comment: Then try `$("#league_id").remove()` do you still get the value?

Comment: .remove() completely removes the element from the DOM.. Removing just the attribute should be sufficient

Comment: I know that :) This was just ment more for debugging purpouse. Well maybe there is another code on the page which for example changes the value of `$("#league_id")` on form submit?

Comment: @JurisVaiders - pretty much.  I had naming conflicts.  My fault.  Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My own fault, had a name collision in the elements

Answer (score 0):

Think this is the culprit

```
$("#league_id").val(null)..
```

If you inspect the DOM after making it **null** the value field is still existent , may be the DOM was not refreshed yet..

So when the form is posted maybe the value="11" is being sent.

Why don't you try removing the attribute completely and then try again..

```
 $('#league_id').removeAttr('value');
```